# how to get multi-dimensional array data with another one-dimension array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

What I'd like to do is have a function that accepts two arguments, both arrays, the first being a one-dimensional array of varying lengths and the second is a multi-dimensional array of varying depths and lengths. The first array is never associative, the second is always a fully associative array.

This function would return the requested value from the multi-dimensional array as indicated by the first array.

Assume that the first array will always be hand-written and passed to this function. Meaning the developer always knows there is a value to be returned from the multi-dimensional array and would never pass a request to the function where a value did not exist.

I think the code below is the best example at what I'm trying to achieve.

```
//Example multi-dimensional array
$multi = array(
        'fruit' => array(
                        'red' => array(
                                    'strawberries' => '$2.99/lb',
                                    'apples' => '$1.99/lb'
                                    ),
                        'green' => array(
                                    'honeydew' => '$3.39/lb',
                                    'limes' => '$0.75/lb'
                                    )
                    ),
        'vegetables' => array(
                        'yellow' => array(
                                    'squash' => '$1.29/lb',
                                    'bellpepper' => '$0.99/lb'
                                    ),
                        'purple' => array(
                                    'eggplant' => '$2.39/lb'
                                    )
                    ),
        'weeklypromo' => '15% off',
        'subscribers' => array(
                            'user1@email.com' => 'User 1',
                            'user2@email.com' => 'User 2',
                            'user3@email.com' => 'User 3',
                            'user4@email.com' => 'User 4'
                            )
        );

//Example one-dimensional array
$single = array('fruit', 'red', 'apples');

function magicfunc($single, $multi) {
    //some magic here that looks something like below
    $magic_value = $multi[$single[0]][$single[1]][$single[2]];
    return $magic_value;
}

//Examples:

print magicfunc(array('fruit', 'red', 'apples'), $multi);
Output:
$1.99/lb

print magicfunc(array('subscribers', 'user3@email.com'), $multi);
Output:
User 3

print magicfunc(array('weeklypromo'), $multi);
Output:
15% off
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This returns the values as requested:

```
function magicfunc($single, $multi) {
    while (true) {
        if (!$single) {
            break;
        }
        $searchIndex = array_shift($single);

        foreach ($multi as $k => $val) {
            if ($k == $searchIndex) {
                $multi = $val;
                continue 2;
            }
        }
    }
    return $multi;
}
```